# Show/hide layout in gridview onitemclick

Tags: android, gridview

I want to show/hide layout on OnItemClickListener.Now I am clicking an item it shows layout after that i am clicking an another item previous one is hide new one is visible.I want when click on same item visible one should be hide thats it.Thanks.

```
             private View previousItem;

             movie_gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            if (previousItem != null) {
                LinearLayout buy_dvd_or_movie_layout = (LinearLayout) previousItem
                        .findViewById(R.id.buy_dvd_or_movie_layout);
                buy_dvd_or_movie_layout.startAnimation(slideUp);
                buy_dvd_or_movie_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            LinearLayout buy_dvd_or_movie_layout = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.buy_dvd_or_movie_layout);
            buy_dvd_or_movie_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            previousItem = view;

        }
    });
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @WernerHenze hi I want to show/hide layout on gridview onitemclick

Comment: Try calling .invalidate() on the views to update them upon clicking. e.g. buy_dvd_or_movie_layout.invalidate()

Comment: @DrissNakayamaSamy adapter.invalidate() right?

Comment: @Priyan That is a requirement, not a question. Does your code try to implement that behavior? If yes, what doesn't work? What do you get, what do you expect?

Comment: @Priyan, yes you can try that. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @WernerHenze i am loading list of images in gridview with image and text.When i click on particular gridview item hidden layout will come above imageview after that clicking the same item on gridview visible item should be gone thats it.

Comment: @DrissNakayamaSamy  if (previousItem != null) {
     LinearLayout buy_dvd_or_movie_layout = (LinearLayout) previousItem
       .findViewById(R.id.buy_dvd_or_movie_layout);
     buy_dvd_or_movie_layout.startAnimation(slideUp);
     buy_dvd_or_movie_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    LinearLayout buy_dvd_or_movie_layout = (LinearLayout) view
      .findViewById(R.id.buy_dvd_or_movie_layout);
    buy_dvd_or_movie_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    previousItem = view;
    buy_dvd_or_movie_layout.invalidate();

Comment: @DrissNakayamaSamy sorry its not working

Comment: @DrissNakayamaSamy got my problem?

Comment: Use View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE

Comment: @vilpe89 got my problem?

Comment: Hi please some one help me.